# How to get a blob from Javascript with Blazor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, blazor, crop

I'm using `SixLabors.ImageSharp` to crop images with Javascript JQuery and all is working rigth but when i need to get the image cropped i don't know how can i get the image without refresh the page and without do a POST.

I'm using [Tutexchange](https://tutexchange.com/how-to-crop-and-resize-image-in-asp-net-core/) tutorial and they obtain the image by a POST method (and i dont wanna do it like that) i think about run a method and with Blazor get the file encoded base64 but when i do it i cant get the `reader.result` because is inside the onloadend event.
How can i get a image blob without a POST method and without save the image in a folder to read with Blazor?

I tried passing the onloadend reader.result with a method and await with a bucle while to return it when is done but value never is different than `null` and i tested if the cropper work with a console.log() and all is right with it:

```
function InitializeCroppie(div_width, div_height) {
basic = $('#main-cropper').croppie
    ({
        enableExif: true,
        url: '/images/ChooseImage.png',
        viewport: { width: div_width, height: div_height },
        boundary: { width: div_width, height: div_height },
        showZoomer: false,
        format: 'png' //'jpeg'|'png'|'webp'
    });
//Reading the contents of the specified Blob or File
function readFile(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#main-cropper').croppie('bind', {
                url: e.target.result
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

// Change Event to Read file content from File input
$('#select').on('change', function () { readFile(this); });
}

var returnThisValue;
async function GetImageCroped() {
  returnThisValue = null;
  var blob = await basic.croppie('result', 'blob');
  var reader = new FileReader();
  if (blob != null) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        SetValue(reader.result);
        console.log(reader.result);
    }
  }

  while (returnThisValue == null) {
    //Waiting...
  }

  return returnThisValue;
}

function SetValue(value) {
  returnThisValue = value;
}

function GetImageValue() {
  return returnThisValue;
}
```

If is impossible without a POST method how can i receive it without reload the page.

**EDIT:**
I'm doing some test to know if is possible that js let blazor know when put the image in the localStorage to get it synchronic way with Blazor.
**AFTER TEST:** I tried to get the image with Blazored.LocalStorage and i cannot Chrome has a problem with "big data".

Comment: Whether the image is uploaded from the user or obtained from the backend?  And when is the image uploaded to the page? (When opening the page?)

Comment: 1)The image is obtained from the user.  2) After the user drop it on the container or select a image.

Comment: Why do not you use blazor's InputFile to upload file? [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0)  You can add a javascript event. When user select the file, blazor call this javascript.

Comment: @user1986237 yes, i can use it but it no will help me with get a image from Javascript. Javascript method get the current image and crop it after that convert the Blob to base64. Adding a InputFile how can help me? If i put the source code obtained from the cropped image in a InputFile i could put it in database with Blazor. Is that do you want to said or you a another idea?

Comment: It is based on the [code](https://tutexchange.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/WebCropper.7z) you refer to, because I do not know your blazor structrue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a JavaScript listener event. It will trigger another event when updating the localstorage. It should be loaded when the page is initialized.

```
var orignalSetItem = localStorage.setItem;
localStorage.setItem = function (key, newValue) {
    var setItemEvent = new Event("setItemEvent");
    setItemEvent.key = key;
    setItemEvent.newValue = newValue;
    window.dispatchEvent(setItemEvent);
    orignalSetItem.apply(this, arguments);
};
window.addEventListener("setItemEvent", function (e) {
    if (e.key == 'image') {
        var _this = localStorage.getItem("image")
        if (_this != e.newValue) {
            console.log(e.newValue)
            //call method which sends this blob
        } else {
            console.log('key->');
            console.log(e.newValue)
        }
    }
});
```

Trigger method.

```
 $('#btnupload').on('click', function ()
{ 
    basic.croppie('result', 'blob').then(function (blob)
    {
        localStorage.setItem('image', blob)
        //...
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct but if you test your code you will notice that the image cannot be retrieved with Blazor because the populars browsers like Google Chrome has problems with pass "big data" from the localstorage. Also i tried run it in Firefox and Microsoft Edge and i got the same problem.

Comment: I said that cause i tried with a similiar way and it not work. If this method cannot work in Google Chrome i give up because the most poblation use Google Chrome.

Comment: If you tested your code with Blazor and it can run correctly please correct me.

Comment: @MAERT, please tell me your file size. Because the file I tested is less than 1M.

Comment: i tested with a 623KB file size.  I used Blazored.LocalStorage to try get the blob from Local Storage. Which library did you used in Blazor side? The image was saved correctly in the LocalStorage but i cannot get it.

Comment: Now i notice that you put the blob directly to the Local Storage. I converted the blob to base64 string and after that i tried to get it. May be this is my problem. Let me try....

Comment: Yes, I save the blob derectly, popular browsers limit the size of local storage to about 5M.

Comment: Your code works fine in Javascript side but when i need to get the image from Local storage i have problems in Blazor side. I can set and get the image in JS side thats right but when i need to do the same in Blazor side i can't do it. When i tested with a png 11kb image size all works fine but when i tested with a 24kb and 4kb images size all broke and i don't know why this happend and isn't the size of the image. I need an answer that works in also in Blazor side. I'll add my Blazor code.